# How to calculate the difference between 2 rotations in SceneKit / ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I have a node in ARKit for which I've registered its rotation at some point.
Later on, I'm registering the node's current rotation once again and I need to know the difference between those two.

I need this in the `simdRotation` format because I'll need to inject it to the `simdPivot` to then turn my node accordingly.  So I need the angle and the vector of axis of rotation.  (So I will turn this simdRotation into a rotation matrix and along with the translation, feed it to the simdPivot - this I know how to do).

I've been trying so many different things and I can't find how to calculate this difference nor do I find any documentation or site explaining how to accomplish this.

I tried maybe using the `simdEulerAngles` or the `simdOrientation`.
I found a method to convert the eulerAngles into an orientation quaternion.  But from here I don't know how to convert it back to the rotation format.

I need to do this in 2 places in my code.  In one place I'll need the difference of rotation in all 3 directions and in the 2nd place I'll just need the difference of rotation around the y-axis.

So what's the correct way to find the difference between 2 rotations?
I feel like it must be much simpler than how it currently looks to me.
Maybe I can convert both to rotation matrices and from here there's a clear formula?

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ultimately figured this out.
I turn each rotation into a rotation matrix - in my case I use a simd_float4x4 because I later combine it with a translation (as 4th column) into a transform matrix.
I do something like this:

```
let newRotationInTransformMatrix = simd_float4x4(SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(currentRotation!.w, currentRotation!.x, currentRotation!.y, currentRotation!.z))
```

(If anyone knows how to create such a matrix directly in the simd world, please comment.  I didn't know so I first created it in the SCN notation and then converted to the sims format).

I do the same with the other rotation.
Then to find the difference between the two, I multiply one matrix by the transpose of the other:

```
let pivotRotationMatrix = lastMazeRotationInTransformMatirx * newRotationInTransformMatrix.transpose
```

This worked for me.  I hope it can help others as well!